# Objective-C Calling a selector that the compiler does not believe exists (even though we know it does)

Tags: objective-c, selector

I have this code in a prepareForSegue method

```
    // Get destination view
    UIViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    //See if it responds to a selector
    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setSomethingOrOther:)]) {
        //if so call it with some data
        [viewController setSomethingOrOther:something];
    }
```

The code above means I do not have to include a reference to the actual class of the view controller being segue'd to. I can more loosely couple the two view controllers and just check if it responds to some property being set on it.

The problem is that when I do this I get the following compile time error:

*No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'setSomethingOrOther:'*

which is true of course. I know I could get around it by including a reference to the view but I would prefer to keep it separated. How can I work around this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `performSelector:aSelector` method, then you can call an undeclared selector.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like an idiot. Have used this a fair bit in other scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

```
[viewController performSelector:@selector(setSomethingOrOther:) 
                     withObject:something];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this

```
[(id)viewController setSomethingOrOther:something];
```

in some situation, but I the compiler will complain if it does not know about the existence of setSomethingOrOther: at all, like a library that you haven't included the header for.

Comment: That's actually the point of this question; I don't want to include the header at all. I want more separation between my ViewControllers.

Comment: You didn't read my answer properly, this will work if the method is defined somewhere in you project you just don't want to included the header.