# ui scroll view declares selector for modal present animated

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

when presenting a modal view to allow address book picking.  I get error

`No visible @interface uiScrollView declares selector for modal presented animated`

here

`[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];`

I think I need to use `performSelector:@selector` as researched in the following post

[Objective-C Calling a selector that the compiler does not believe exists (even though we know it does)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954886/objective-c-calling-a-selector-that-the-compiler-does-not-believe-exists-even-t)

However im unsure how to implement in my code

```
 - (id)initWithCertificate:(Certificate *)certificate
 {



if ((self = [super initWithCertificate:certificate])) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MinorWorksPart1" owner:self options:nil];
    self.view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height);

    self.dateMinorWorksCompletedField.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"dateMinorWorksCompleted"]).value;

    DebugLog(@"dateMinorWorksCompleted attribute value is %@", ([self attributeWithName:@"dateMinorWorksCompleted"]).value);
    DebugLog(@"Certificate reference is %@", self.certificate.reference);
    self.certificateReferenceField.text = (self.certificate.reference != nil ? self.certificate.reference : @"");
    self.clientField.text = ([self attributeWithName:@"client"]).value;
    self.detailsOfDeparturesField.text = ([self attributeWithName:@"detailsOfDepartures"]).value;
    self.addressOfTheMinorWorks.text = ([self attributeWithName:@"addressOfTheMinorWorks"]).value;
    self.descriptionOfMinorWorksField.text = ([self attributeWithName:@"descriptionOfMinorWorks"]).value;
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't do you any good because, as the error says, the scroll view does not implement that method. It'll fail the same way. Instead of `self` (which I suspect is you UIScrollView), use a reference to the `UIViewController`.

As a side note, according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a), you are now supposed to use:

`- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`

Which you can call in this way if you have no completion block:

`[myViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];`

Comment: Thanks for answer, and heads up on the other bit.  Ive referenced the ViewController as suggested but get `No known class method selector for present modal View Controller animated` error?

Comment: I think it might be because this is code I've picked up form a third party and has a custom class for the view controller, im not sure how to implement a class method for presenting the adress book modal view